# Javascript 'not defined' error when declaring default function parameter matching to a constant?

Tags: javascript, parameters, syntax-error, constants

Just discovered some weird error that reads:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: symbol is not defined
```

Code in question:

```
const symbol='tNEOUSD';
function get_position(symbol=symbol){
    console.log(symbol);
}
get_position();
```

How come it's not defined? That's a really weird!

On the other hand if I use a different parameter name it works just fine:

```
const symbol='tNEOUSD';
function get_position(sym=symbol){
    console.log(sym);
}
get_position();
```

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Defaults are evaluated when the function is called, and with parameters up to and including themselves in scope. Kind of like writing `let x = 5; { let x = x; }`.

Answer (score -2):

You cant use a variable which is already declared outside as a parameter. [image]

Comment: That message seems to refer to previously having used `const symbol` or `let symbol` in your session. The code in that painting works standing alone.

Comment: @ZMXX please [be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)